# PHP Delete returns an error

Tags: php, function, output, delete-file

Whenever I try to delete the `counter.txt` using PHP, I always get an error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function delete() in C:\XAMPP\htdocs\jellykat\control-panel.php on line 12

Here is my code:

```
<?php delete("counter.txt"); ?>
```

What's wrong with it? Can you suggest me ways on the other methods that I can delete the `counter.txt`?

Don't blame me. I got the `delete()` method from here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_delete.asp

Comment: That isn't how you delete a file in PHP. Try `unlink` instead.

Comment: Dont use w3schools to look up PHP function. Always use php.net.

Comment: As per what [**PHP states**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.delete.php) on the subject - *"This is a dummy manual entry to satisfy those people who are looking for `unlink()` or `unset()` in the wrong place."*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use [`unlink()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) instead .. there is no such `delete()`

If you see the manual of [`delete()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.delete.php) , It says..

> This is a dummy manual entry to satisfy those people who are looking
> for unlink() or unset() in the wrong place.

So, it should be

```
<?php unlink("counter.txt"); ?>
```

Comment: "dummy" being the "operative" word. +1 ;-)